# SQL-Server Update and Replace some index of character

Tags: sql-server

I need to update and replace all this IP in database and hold some index

> this = ftp://192.168.1.2/Y2018/M2/JNxxxxx
>   to = ftp://192.168.2.2/Y2018/M2/JNxxxxxx

change only IP and hold all index default

Comment: " hold some index", what do you mean by this,

Comment: i need to keep all character without 192.168.1.2 because i need to change only this ip to new ip

Comment: I *think* the OP is implying they want a blanket find and replace across their whole instance; meaning they don't know where their data is stored. I also, however, have no idea what "hold some index" means. To the OP, you need to elaborate much more on this.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

1. mytable with your table name
2. mycolumn with your column name
3. 'newvalue' with your new ip
4. 'myvalue' with your ip to change

   `UPDATE MYTABLE
   SET MYCOLUMN = REPLACE(MYCOLUMN, SUBSTRING(MYCOLUMN, 7, CHARINDEX('/', MYCOLUMN, 7)-7) ,'NEWVALUE')
   WHERE MYCOLUMN= 'MYVALUE'`;

Comment: doesn't work, i have try this
UPDATE AP_JobDescription
SET FTPFolder = REPLACE(FTPFolder, SUBSTRING(FTPFolder, 7, CHARINDEX('/', FTPFolder, 7)-7) ,'192.168.2.2')
WHERE FTPFolder= '192.168.1.2'

Comment: your filter is wrong, you should put the whole value in the where clause, like `WHERE FTPFolder= 'ftp://192.168.1.2/Y2018/M2/J232Nxxxxx'`

Comment: Why not `REPLACE(MyColumn, '192.168.1.2', '192.168.2.2')`. I'm not sure MyColumn has a preset value (could have different directories) so not sure thusly fit the OP's vague needs.

Comment: Yes this would make sense if OP wants to change values one by one but i guess he is looking for something more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update only *IP Address* use `STUFF()` function

```
UPDATE table 
SET Col = STUFF(Col, 7, 11, '192.168.2.2')
```

Here, i assumed the fixed length of `IP`'s

**EDIT**:- Use dynamic length approach

```
UPDATE table 
SET Col = STUFF(Col, 7, (PATINDEX('%[^://]/%', Col)+1)-7, '192.168.100.254')
```

Comment: hey...but its dont work with 192.168.100.254 when IP octet is 3 its doesn't work...

Comment: @VansavangTHONGPASEUTH.. use dynamic approach with `patindex()` function

Comment: Wow... you are so nice its Successfully
Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
declare @s varchar(50) = 'ftp://192.168.1.2/Y2018/M2/JNxxxxx', @ip varchar(50) = '192.168.2.2'

select @s, STUFF(@s,
                 --index of //
                 CHARINDEX('//', @s, 1) + 2,
                 --length, that actual IP holds in a string
                 CHARINDEX('/', @s, CHARINDEX('//', @s, 1) + 2) - CHARINDEX('//', @s, 1) - 2,
                 --new IP address to paste in place of an old one
                 @ip)
```